# Migrating problem from Joomla to WP

Tags: plugins, migration

My summer job is to migrate blog and web site from Joomla CMS to Wordpress and have no Wordpress installed on server and have no PHP in use. Cause of PHP is in no use, that excluses using Plugin -tools like CMS2CMS. Is there any way to do that in a clever way and in an automated way? Automated way would be better alternative than manual way.

I used Joomla Backup -extensions and now I have my whole site backuped as a JPA -file. Is it possible to convert it to Wordpress import -file in some way without having Wordpress server -installation ? I haven't found a tool for that yet, and been looking for couple of hours with Google.

Comment: What do you mean by 'and have no PHP in use'?

Comment: The admin has not enabled PHP in the server in which one I'm working with. That's what I mean.

Comment: Had you considered just running WP locally on your computer? That's pretty much staple for development anyway, few people work directly on remote servers.

Comment: Stand -alone and local Wordpress installation would be the great alternative for developement, if I got the admin permissions to install any software on my laptop. But I can't count on it since I'm not super user.

Comment: How much content is there? It may not be too difficult to export as a CSV, move the data around in Excel and then import in to the WordPress format.

Comment: You want to move content from one PHP based system to another without using PHP? How? And why?

Comment: JPA file is nearly 50 MB. Perhaps I'm going to give a chance for that CSV -thing. I got this job from my boss, so I have to get it done somehow or other way before starting to modify webpages.

Comment: If your site is currently running on Joomla then you have PHP installed on the server. You might check these guys out:

http://gconverters.com/convert-joomla-to-wordpress/

Comment: Joomla uses PHP, yet PHP is not available? Perhaps we misunderstand, is there a server migration also involved? I don't think you have the tools or the access to do what has been asked of you. You can't install tools locally, and they aren't available on the server. At a very minimum you require a WordPress installation to migrate the content to

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to magically extract and migrate articles from within a JPA backup file directly into WordPress.

You can use Akeeba eXtract Wizard to extract the database file from the JPA file and then you have access to the article HTML via a text editor but you'll need a working copy of WordPress to be able to import the articles by whichever method you choose.

You could set up a local development environment using WAMP, MAMP or LAMP etc but the simplest and quickest course of action is probably to purchase a web hosting plan and work on this on-line. A web hosting plan costs very little and you can pay by the month and cancel it after you no longer need it if you have no further use.